# IE 11 dpi issue opening from java 8

Tags: java, internet-explorer-11, dpi

On a high dpi display when I click a hyperlink to a jsp from a java 8 application IE 11 webpage opens shrunk/compressed/small

Already have edited Windows settings for the Java application to deal with the swing high dpi issue. So Java is a normal size.

It seems when we open a link to our jsp from within our java 8 application the IE 11 window does not honor the high dpi fix and the browser page content is compressed to a very small size. But if we open the same jsp page from the browser NOT opening it from with the Java 8 application there is no problem

Comment: If the **same HTML** opens differently from Java vs directly, then it appears that your Java code adds some HTTP header that affects the result. Since we can't see what your Java code is doing, it's difficult to help.

Comment: Only description about the issue will not help us to understand the issue properly and find the cause for it. It will be better if you post any sample code with detailed steps which can be helpful for reproducing the issue. We can try to make a test with your sample code and try to check the results. Thanks for your understanding.